# Best way to include a "singularity" in a SmoothHistogram?

Tags: plotting, data, histograms

I have a dataset like this:

```
data = {0,0,1.1,1.3,0,0,3.4,0,0,2.3,0,0 .....}
```

You can imagine that `data` is generated from a probability distribution of the form:

$$p(x)=w_0\delta(x) + (1 - w_0)f(x)$$

where $f(x)$ is a smooth probability density function, $\delta$ is Dirac-delta function, and $0\le w_0 \le 1$.

That is, there is a finite probability that $x=0$.

I want to plot an histogram of `data`. If I exclude `0`, then a `SmoothHistogram` is fine. But now I want to include also in this plot the  frequency of `0`. In this case, `SmoothHistogram` performs poorly, since it tries to draw a smooth peak centered at 0.

Can you suggest a better way to visualize `data`? Note that I know that the location of the singularity is at `0`.

Comment: might data look something like this `Join[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[2, 1], 2000], 
 ConstantArray[0, {100}]]` ?

Comment: @george2079 Try putting the `0`'s in random positions. Other than that, yes.

Comment: First you might consider rewriting the density to $p(x)=w_0 \delta(x)+(1-w_0)f(x)$.  That makes $f$ a legitimate probability density function.  Second, why not just display a legend that states $X$ takes the value zero with probability $w_0$ otherwise $X$ takes the random value from the distribution $f(x)$ described by the smooth histogram?  If you want to display a density, then as stated below by @george2079, there really is no appropriate scaling if a smooth histogram is displayed.  Alternatively, you could plot the cumulative distribution function which would have a jump at zero.

Comment: @JimBaldwin The main issue is that I am comparing different datasets (which probably have different $w_0$'s). If I just do a SmoothHistogram of the datasets removing `0`, I don't get a plot that reflects that there may be different values of $w_0$ involved, since all the SmoothHistograms will get normalized to 1, instead of to $1-w_0$ (I rewrote the density as you suggested, thanks).

Comment: As mentioned below as long as the bar widths are constant and the area of the bar at zero is the estimate of $w_0$, then you'd be imparting information in a consistent fashion.  And because it is the density/probability mass function $p$ that you want to describe, the area under $f$ should be $1-w_0$ - so just multiply the resulting density values for $f$ by $1-w_0$.

Comment: Oops!  I see that @wolfies already mentioned the scaling down (multiplying by $1-w_0$ to get the area of $f$ to $1-w_0$ and the total area to 1.0).  I second that.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you just do something like this:

```
data = RandomSample[Join[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[2, 1], 2000],
    ConstantArray[0, {100}]]];
Histogram[data]
```

[image]

```
SmoothHistogram[Select[data, # != 0 &], 
 Epilog -> Line[{{0, 0}, {0, .15}}], AxesOrigin -> {-2, 0}]
```

[image]

I cant see a sensible way to scale that line (It really goes to Infinity).

also the overall smooth plot ought to be scaled down somehow something like this should do:

```
 SmoothHistogram[...]/.Line[x_?(Length[#] > 3 &)] :> 
               Line[{1, Count[data, 0]/Length@data} # & /@ x]
```

In this case the scale change is so small its not worth showing another plot.

Edit:

here is an idea, pick a bin width around your singularity, then you can assign an appropriate height to a bar on the chart:

```
bin = .1;
inbin = Select[data, Abs[#] < bin &] // Length;
hbin = inbin/Length[data]/(2 bin) // N
SmoothHistogram[Select[data, Abs[#] > bin &], 
  Epilog -> Rectangle[{-bin, 0}, {bin, hbin}], 
  AxesOrigin -> {-2, 0}] /. 
 Line[x_?(Length[#] > 3 &)] :> 
  Line[{1, 1 - inbin/Length@data} # & /@ x]
```

[image]

note this counts all the data in the bin not just the exact zeros.  This last chart looks a little different because its using a new random data set by the way.

Comment: I suspect the SmoothedHistogram will always be constructed such that the density under the curve is 1 (even if we remove the 0 data from the curve). If so, one would need to manually 'scale down' the Smootherhistrogram plot by whatever proportion of the data are excluded (the zeroes)

Comment: Could you use `WeightedData[]` as an input to `SmoothHistogram[]` to weight according to if it is zero or not, then add back in the line?

Comment: I don't think the line should go to infinity. The height of the line (maybe it is more stylish to use a bar?) should represent the weight $w_0$ of $0$, or the frequency of $0$'s in the dataset.

Comment: @becko: To make any sense the area of the bar at zero would have to be $w_0$.  And because the width is completely arbitrary (and "technically" should have a width of zero), I don't see that any appropriate knowledge/information would be forthcoming unless...there were multiple figures and an arbitrary bar width would be consistent among the figures.

Comment: You estimate $w_0$  from the data, say by counting the `0`'s. The width is of course arbitrary, it's just visually more appealing, I think.

Answer (score 1):

This is what we get playing with the parameters of `SmoothHistogram` and `SmoothKernelDistribution`:

```
data = RandomSample[Join[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[2, 1], 2000], 
    ConstantArray[0, {100}]]];
Histogram[data]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
SmoothHistogram[data, {"Adaptive", .1, .001}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
SmoothHistogram[data, {"Adaptive", .05, .01}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
dist = SmoothKernelDistribution[data, {"Adaptive", .1, .001}];

Plot[PDF[dist, x], {x, -4, 4}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]